# Find if an array can produce a sum n with k number of elements

Tags: java, recursion

Given an int array that may contain duplicates. I need to find out whether the array can produce a `sum` with `k` elements?

I'm trying to use recursion for now but I'm not getting anywhere at the moment. I have a problem with getting the base-case right.

```
    static boolean groupSum(int[] nums, int k, int sum) {
    
            if (sum == 0)
                return true;
    
            if (k > nums.length || sum != 0)
                return false;
            if (groupSum(nums, k, sum - nums[k - k] - nums[k - k + 1] - nums[k - k + 2]))
                return true;
            if (groupSum(nums, k, sum - nums[k - k + 1] - nums[k - k + 2] - nums[k - k + 3]))
                return true;
    
            else
                return false;
    
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **base case** of your recursive method is incorrect: `sum == 0` isn't a sufficient condition you also have to check whether `k == 0`. If the `sum` is `0` but you still have to use a few more elements then the result `true` is incorrect.

The **recursive part** of the method has some mistakes in it as well. The number of elements summed up `k` never gets decremented.

Also, you have to track a *position* in the array. I mean you need to iterate over the array. And while iterating for each element there are only **two options**: *apply it* (decrement the `k` and subtract current value from the *sum*) or *discard it*. In both cases, you have to increment the *position* that you are passing as an argument.

That is how it could be fixed:

```
    public static boolean groupSum(int[] nums, int k, int pos, int sum) {
        if (sum == 0 && k == 0) {
            return true;
        }
        if (sum < 0) {
            return false;
        }

        boolean result = false;
        for (int i = pos; i < nums.length; i++) {
            boolean takeElement = groupSum(nums, k - 1, pos + 1, sum - nums[i]);
            boolean discardElement = groupSum(nums, k, pos + 1, sum);
            result = takeElement || discardElement;
            if (result) { // a combination that yield the target sum was found
                break;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

There's another option how to implement this method. But **caution**: it will be *slower* and significantly *increases memory consumption*.

This approach requires creating a **copy** of the given array with a *length decremented* by **1** at each recursive method call and pass it as an argument. In this version, an *element at position* `0` is always used when the method is called, therefore it doesn't require to track the position in the array. The main logic remains the same: a *new element* can be used either to *contribute* the `sum` or can be *discarded*.

```
    public static boolean groupSum(int[] nums, int k, int sum) {
        if (sum == 0 && k == 0) {
            return true;
        }
        if (sum < 0 || nums.length == 0) {
            return false;
        }

        boolean takeElement = groupSum(Arrays.copyOfRange(nums, 1, nums.length), k - 1, sum - nums[0]);
        boolean discardElement = groupSum(Arrays.copyOfRange(nums, 1, nums.length), k, sum);

        return takeElement || discardElement;
    }
```

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // sum of 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 yields 15 - expected true
        System.out.println(groupSum(new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}, 5, 0, 15));
        // it's impossible with only one element - expected false
        System.out.println(groupSum(new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}, 1, 0, 10));
        // sum of 4, 5, 6 yields 15 - expected true
        System.out.println(groupSum(new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}, 3, 0, 15));
    }
```

**output**

```
true
false
true
```

Comment: Can it be done without tracking pos?

Comment: @Ernest In order to examine the array contents you have to iterate over the array.  There's no way around it.

Comment: @Ernest As an alternative, at each method call you can pass the copy of the array with a length decremented by 1. But it will be slower and will increase memory consumption.